# Devexpress: AspxGridView's OnCustomButtonCallback event is not reponsing for custom edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have written this program to edit **ASPxGridView's** data throw **custom button**. When I click on the custom button, it's calling back normally and back process is working fine but not returning any value for *edit*. That means their is no data retrive to the view for edit. What can I do now? Some body please help me?

Aspx:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ASPxGridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVaccineSet" Theme="MaterialCompact" EnableTheming="True" OnInit="ASPxGridView1_OnInit" OnCustomButtonCallback="ASPxGridView1_OnCustomButtonCallback">
<SettingsDataSecurity AllowInsert="False" AllowEdit="False" AllowDelete="False"></SettingsDataSecurity>

<SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True"></SettingsSearchPanel>

<Columns>

<dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" ShowClearFilterButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" uttonRenderMode="Image">
<CustomButtons>
<dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btDelete" Visibility="AllDataRows">
<Image ToolTip="Delete" Url="…/Images/delete.png"></Image>
</dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
<dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btEdit" Text="Edit" Visibility="AllDataRows">
<Image ToolTip="Delete" Url="…/Images/edit.png"></Image>
</dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
</CustomButtons>
</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Id" ReadOnly="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Visible="False" VisibleIndex="1">
<EditFormSettings Visible="False"></EditFormSettings>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Quantity" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="EntryBy" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Visible="False" VisibleIndex="6"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="Type" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2">
<PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTypes" TextField="CattleName" ValueField="Id"></PropertiesComboBox>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="Gender" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3">
<PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGender" TextField="Gender" ValueField="Id"></PropertiesComboBox>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="VaccineId" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">
<PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVaccine" TextField="VaccineName" ValueField="Id"></PropertiesComboBox>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
</Columns>

</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

C#:

```
Hashtable GetValues = null;

string[] valueFields = new string[] { "Id", "Type", "Gender", "VaccineId", "Quantity", "EntryBy" };
protected void ASPxGridView1_OnCustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e)
{
ASPxGridView ASPxGridView1 = sender as ASPxGridView;
string id = "", qty = "", vId = "";
GetValues = new Hashtable();
foreach (string fieldName in valueFields)
{
GetValues[fieldName] = this.ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, fieldName);
if (fieldName == "Id")
{
id = this.ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, fieldName).ToString();
}
}

if (e.ButtonID == "btDelete")
{

//Server-side actions performed before showing popup here
ExecuteQuery("Delete CattleVaccineSet Where Id='" + id + "'");
}
else
{
DataTable tbl = ReturnDataTable("Select * From CattleVaccineSet Where Id='" + id + "'");
foreach (DataRow dtr in tbl.Rows)
{
txtQty.Text = dtr["Quantity"].ToString();
cmbVaccine.Value = dtr["VaccineId"].ToString();
}

lblId.Text = id;
messageLevel.Text = "Edit Mode Activated";
submitButton.Text = "Update";
}
}
```